# Using IIF in Proc SQL

Tags: sas

I want to translate the following snippet of code for use in `Proc SQL` for `SAS`:

`SUM( IIF( INLIST( a.Department, DptGI, DptOncology, DptSurgery ), 1, 0 )) as TotalApts,;`

However `IIF()` is not recognized by `PROC SQL`.

Can I implement an `if/else` or some kind of `CASE` statement?

None of that seems to be working for me.

Comment: what do you have and whay you want as output. someone can easily help you, if you can explain this

Answer (score 1):

The SAS version of `IIF` is [`IFN` or `IFC`](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/06/07/ifn-function-versus-if-thenelse-sas.html), depending on numeric or character *return value* (doesn't matter what the input columns are, just what you want back).  As long as you're using it in native SAS PROC SQL (and not pass-through SQL) this should work.

However, `INLIST` is also not a SAS function, you'd have to rewrite that to a normal `in` operator as well.

You should be able to use `case when` statements as well, however, if you would like help with those you can post your code that you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

`IIF()` is not an `SQL` function.  It might be a function that is implemented as an extension in some version of `SQL`,  most likely those created by Microsoft.

I am not sure what `INLIST()` is either.  I will assume it is some type of test of whether the first argument is in the other arguments.  If so you could replace it with one of the SAS functions `WHICHN()` or `WHICHC()`, depending on whether the values in the variables are numbers or strings.

The normal `SQL` syntax for that type of operation is `CASE`.

```
SUM( case when ( a.Department= DptGI) then 1
          when ( a.Department=DptOncology) then 1
          when ( a.Department=DptSurgery ) then 1
      else 0 end
    ) as TotalApts
```

If you are just trying to get result of 1 or 0 and you are ok with using SAS specific syntax then you can just sum the result of the boolean expression.

```
SUM( (a.Department=DptGI) or (a.Department=DptOncology)
     or (a.Department=DptSurgery)) as TotalApts
```

Now if `DPTGI` and the other values are constants and not variables then you could use the `IN` operator.

```
SUM(a.Department in ('GI','Oncology','Surgery')) as TotalApts
```